# Why does my HTTP POST response come as an error?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, post

I have an Angular page where a user chooses two PDF's and then they get uploaded to the API. There they get parsed and return the URL of the comparison. The returned URL then gets displayed in a iframe.

For debugging I've set a static return value of "https://google.ch".

Why am I getting an error when the statuscode is 200?

The POST method:

```
onSubmit() {
        console.log('Submitted');
        const formModel = this.prepareSave();
        this.loading = true;
        this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/demo', formModel)
            .subscribe(response => {
                console.log(response);
                const returnValue = JSON.stringify(response);
                console.log('parsed: ', returnValue);
                this.comparejobdataService.url = response.toString();
                this.router.navigate(['/draftable']);
            });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.loading = false;
        }, 10000);
    }
```

Spring Boot

```
@PostMapping("/demo")
    String pdfDiff(@RequestParam("file1") MultipartFile file1, @RequestParam("file2") MultipartFile file2) {
        System.out.println("File 1: " + file1);
        System.out.println("File 2: " + file2);
        return "https://google.ch";
    }
```

The Error I'm getting returned (posting as a picture as the structure is easier to read)
[image]

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: `JSON.parse: unexpected character` - what did you *expect* to get from parsing `"https://google.ch"` as JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the response of the call is not a valid JSON.